# Styling image in CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, image, tags, css-selectors

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here, the css works when i replace the `.1{}` with `img{}`. Shouldn't I also be able to use `img.1{}` or `.1 img{}`

Here's the **UPDATED** HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="clouds">
<img id="cheese" src="cloud.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the **UPDATED** CSS

```
  body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#0088ff;
    font-family:helvetica;
}
#clouds{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
#cheese img{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Right now all that works is        img{}

Comment: hi now first of you  check to this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: so why doesn't it work with a text id now. That is valid code isn't it?

Comment: You're referencing the image in CSS using wrong selectors! Read the basics. Change it to img#cheese {

Comment: Try to this css  img#cheese{
    display:none;
}

Comment: or u can juts change id to class.it should work then.

Comment: or try to this #clouds > img{display:none;}

Answer (score 6):

Change the class name from **1** to something that starts with a letter and try again.

After all [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors).

EDIT:

I see you have some problems with basic things.

If your image has an ID like `<img id="foo" src="" />` then you reference in CSS using `img#foo { }` (tag + hash + identifier) or just using id without providing type of the tag: `#foo { }`.

Comment: Classes have to start with letters. It's a thing. If you rename .1 to .class-1, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

> Numbers at the beginning of a class name are not illegal in the CSS
>   grammar.
>
> "The name can contain characters a-z, A-Z, digits 0-9, period, hyphen,
>   escaped characters, Unicode characters 161-255, as well as any Unicode
>   character as a numeric code, however, they cannot start with a dash or
>   a digit."

**You are just specifying the name the wrong way.**

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html

Try to this way according to updated your question

```
img#cheese {
    display:none;
}
```

**or**

```
#clouds>img{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple images then you can use like this:you can use like this:

```
<style>
#clouds{
overflow:hidden;
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
.1{
display:none;
}
.2{
display:block;
}
</style>

<div id="clouds">
<img class="1" src="cloud.png">
<img class="2" src="cloud.png">
</div>
```

Comment: It will but with that solution he won't know what was the issue (class naming).

Comment: yeah but i want multiple images with individual parameters, without making a div for each one. Shouldn't i be able to give and id to an image though?

Comment: Give it an id or a class or refer using data attributes - what suits your needs. It doesn't matter. What matters is using a valid name for classes and ids. :)